# How can I link the serpent compiler to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, pyethapp, serpent

`geth` offers the function `eth.compile.serpent`. However, when I try to provide some source to the compiler, it returns `The method eth_compileSerpent does not exist/is not available`.

I wonder:

- How can I link the serpent compiler with `geth`? I don't see something similar to `eth.setSolc` for the serpent compiler.
- Do I also need to reformat serpent code to be on one line when submitting it to the compiler and how is then indentation handled?